# setup cron in orangeHRM

Tags: php, cron, orangehrm

I am trying to set up a **cron** in ***orangeHRM*** and I can't seem to figure out where to start.

I've done it in some other frameworks, it was simple, as there was a separate module named as command and we set everything inside this command.

Now, inside this ***orangeHRM*** codebase, there's nothing as such and I am lost.

Please guide!

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrangeHRM uses symfony 1.4 framework. You can create "tasks" which can be run in the command line. These can be added to as cron tasks.

Following link will provide you the guide to create symfony tasks (for v1.4):
https://symfony.com/legacy/doc/cookbook/1_1/en/tasks

You can refer an existing task in the OrangeHRM code to help you create one of your own. See below:
https://github.com/orangehrm/orangehrm/blob/master/symfony/plugins/orangehrmAdminPlugin/lib/task/createSupportedLanguageFileTask.class.php